# Node/Express Server with Nginx Reverse Proxy won't load the Angular-App

Tags: html, node.js, angular, express, nginx

This is my first question on Stackoverflow and I researched alot about the Topic, but couldn't find an answer to this Question, I am not sure what is causing the error and I appreciate everyone who is trying to help me :)

I can write normal html in index.html and it works,
but when I include a src or href atrribute to a html tag than this error occurs:

The Error Message I get in the Edge Developer Tool is :

```
GET https://xx.xx.x.xx/runtime.bc33a024b4fd91e9.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET https://xx.xx.x.xx/polyfills.c7b46d3a1275416b.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET https://xx.xx.x.xx/styles.68b2a3d9e76ca2bd.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET https://xx.xx.x.xx/main.b37a7a98997c8bfc.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET https://xx.xx.x.xx/assets/images/lb.ico net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Backend index.js:

```
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")
const helmet = require("helmet");
const compressor = require("compression");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const csv = require("./csv/csv-import")
const pdf = require("./pdf/pdf-import")
const xlsx = require("./xlsx/xlsx-import")
const data = require("./data/data-import");
const ex = require("./data/data-export");
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
const port =  8081;

var corsOptions = {
    origin: "HTTPS://xx.xx.x.xx",
  };

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compressor());
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
http.createServer(app).listen(port, "xx.xx.x.xx");

function main(){
    initial();
}

function initial() {
    console.log("initializing")
    csv.getCsvDataOn(app)
    csv.getCsvDataOff(app)
    xlsx.getXlsxData(app)
    pdf.getPdfData(app)
    pdf.getPdfInput(app)
    data.getDataOn(app)
    data.getDataOff(app)
    data.ReturnDate(app)
    ex.getNameHardware(app)
}

main();
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.x.xx;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://xx.xx.x.xx:8081;
    }
}
```

Angular Index.html (ng build --prod --base-href ./):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Boarding</title>
        <base href="./">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/lb.ico">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
            }
        </style>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Material Icons';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v121/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2');
            }

            .material-icons {
                font-family: 'Material Icons';
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 24px;
                line-height: 1;
                letter-spacing: normal;
                text-transform: none;
                display: inline-block;
                white-space: nowrap;
                word-wrap: normal;
                direction: ltr;
                -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            }
        </style>
        <style>
            .mat-typography {
                font: 400 14px/20px Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;
                letter-spacing: normal
            }

            html,body {
                height: 100%
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.68b2a3d9e76ca2bd.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.68b2a3d9e76ca2bd.css">
        </noscript>
    </head>
    <body class="mat-typography">
        <app-root></app-root>
        <script src="runtime.bc33a024b4fd91e9.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="polyfills.c7b46d3a1275416b.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="main.b37a7a98997c8bfc.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds like nginx or server config - have you checked the permissions on your built files? Does the user that the proxy is running as have permission to access them? Test if it is a proxy problem by accessing the files from the server on port 8081 - if you can, it's proxy troubles, if not it's something about the permissions on your node server.

Comment: @glenatron Thank you yeah, your right it works on the Server, something about nginx reverse proxy is the problem. I am checking the permission and that is propably why it didn't work. Thank you alot :)